# C# Learning MVVM by creating a Login functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to get my head around how MVVM pattern works. Would like to hear some reviews if I am implementing it correctly.

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="Login_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Login_App"
        xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:Login_App.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"


    Title="Login" Height="380" Width="650" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:LoginVM x:Key="vm"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">

        <TextBlock Text="Username"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Password"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Login"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding User}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**LoginView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Login_App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        LoginVM viewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = Resources["vm"] as LoginVM;
            viewModel.Authenticated += ViewModel_Authenticated;
        }

        private void ViewModel_Authenticated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace Login_App.Model
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

This is the structure:

[image]

**LoginVM.cs**

```
namespace Login_App.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private UserModel user;
        public UserModel User
        {
            get { return user; }
            set
            {
                user = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("User");
            }
        }

        private string username;
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                username = value;
                User = new UserModel
                {
                    Username = username,
                    Password = this.Password
                };
                OnPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }

        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                password = value;
                User = new UserModel
                {
                    Username = this.Username,
                    Password = password
                };
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

        public Commands.LoginCommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

        public LoginVM()
        {
            LoginCommand = new Commands.LoginCommand(this);

            user = new UserModel();
        }

        public async void Login()
        {
            bool result = await Helpers.MySQLHelper.Login(User);
            if (result)
            {
                Authenticated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public EventHandler Authenticated;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Commands > LoginCommand.cs**

```
namespace Login_App.ViewModel.Commands
{
    public class LoginCommand : ICommand
    {
        public LoginVM ViewModel { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public LoginCommand(LoginVM vm)
        {
            ViewModel = vm;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            UserModel user = parameter as UserModel;

            if (user == null)
                return false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Username))
                return false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
                return false;

            return true;

        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ViewModel.Login();
        }
    }
}
```

**Helpers > MySQLHelper.cs**

```
namespace Login_App.ViewModel.Helpers
{
    public class MySQLHelper
    {
        // Connection string
        private static string connectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=Logindatabase";

        // Login Functionality
        public static async Task<bool> Login(UserModel user)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*), u.id FROM users u WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            App.UserId = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "Login App Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Login App Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 - Using dapper**

I have been recommended to use Dapper, and I see it is far less coding rather than doing the standard `MySQLCommand cmd = new...` etc..

So here it is.

I have used message box just to see what value will be returned.

```
public class MySQLHelper
{
    // Login Functionality
    public static async Task<bool> Login(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            /// Query to get count of users from the parameters provided by the user.
            /// On successful Login, the details from the database,
            /// will be saved in the <App.xaml.cs> file.

            string mysqlUserDetails = "SELECT COUNT(*), u.id AS UserID, Username, Email, DepartmentID, Inactive" +
                " FROM users u WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = MD5(@Password)";

            using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var userDetails = connection.Query<UserModel>(mysqlUserDetails, new { Username = user.Username, Password = user.Password }).ToList();

                // Determine whether to autherize or not
                if(userDetails.Count == 1)
                {
                    var details = userDetails.First();
                    App.UserId = details.UserID;
                    App.Username = details.Username;
                    App.Email = details.Email;
                    App.DepartmentID = details.DepartmentID;
                    App.Inative = details.Inactive;

                }


                

            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting appears to be off in MySQLHelper.cs around the if/else statement.  you should double check to make sure you don't have any errors there. it could just be a copy paste error, it happens sometimes.

Comment: @Malachi Thank you for that. Have updated the question.

Comment: Use https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapperinstead of ADO.NET. Don't call a class "helper". Don't hardcode a connection string (get it from a config file). Don't mix UI and backend-code (`MessageBox.Show` in your MySqlHelper class).

Comment: @BCdotWEB Hi, the link does not work. How would you show an error message?

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper . Method returns result -> UI level inspects results and shows message if necessary.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thank you for the tip using the `app.config` file, for the connection string. Much appreciated!

Comment: @BCdotWEB See `Edit 1` where amended code to use `Dapper`

Comment: [Relaying Command Logic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) and [Overriding `OnStartup` to instantiate ViewModels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#mainwindowviewmodel-class) can be useful here. I'm not sure that `ResourceDictionary` is the best place to store ViewModel. Learn something about "Composition Root" in MVVM apps.

Comment: @aepot Spasibo :)